# MediaPlayer Cannot resolve method create

Tags: android

**Problem solved!
I had a very dumb fail in the .xml where i forgot an "@+id/"..
also i had to clear the project so this annoying error with R cannot be resolved got away..**

---

After i tries some codes it left the error..
it also displays a notice, that he can't understand R.

Code: http://pastebin.com/X5nrMHK2

---

i got a little problem with the MediaPlayer..

I want to play the Sound eightsound in the res/raw folder when pressing on the Button eight..

Here is my Code:

```
package com.iklikla.eightgame;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button eight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity .this,R.raw.eightsound);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}

}
```

The error is on line 22

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity .this,R.raw.eightsound);
```

It says: Cannot resolve method 'create(com.iklikla.eightgame.MainActivitym ?)

Comment: that line looks fine. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int) Your button is not initialized

Comment: where is eight defined ? Casted to Button ? like eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);

Comment: use getContext() instead of this

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is the `new` keyword. Remove the new keyword and it will work.

`Mediaplayer xyz = Mediaplayer.create(this, R.raw.Filename);`

Answer (score 2):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.end);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Just replace the `R.raw.end` with your own file.

Answer (score 0):

just change MainActivity.this to this !

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eightsound);
          mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: exactly, the mediaplayer is created inside a click event and will not refer to context using 'this'. Activity reference is necessary.

Comment: and define your eight button eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);

Comment: defining the eight button gives the error "Cannot resolve Symbol "R"

Comment: @andreas-heimann you have to define the button eight before listen to OnClick . then define your mp3 sound in res/raw and name it in Lowercase .tell us result

Comment: How do i define the .ogg?

Comment: Problem solved!

I had a very dumb fail in the .xml where i forgot an "@+id/"..
also i had to clear the project so this annoying error with R cannot be resolved got away..

Answer (score 0):

simply remove **this** keyword from the code and it will work.